# Golang and Gin web framework - Execute code after router.Run()

Tags: go, go-gin

I am fairly new to Go, so please excuse me if this is something obvious.

I am busy writing some code in Go for OAuth 2.0 Authentication. Part of this means that I need to have a callback URL available. In my code I need to create a callback endpoint, and once this is up and running I need to call an Authorization endpoint which will then reach out to my callback endpoint.

My problem being that calling Run() in Gin is blocking my execution, so I can't do any further authorization after my callback endpoint is up and running. Is there a way to maybe run this code in a separate GoRoutine so that I can finish my Authorization flow afterwards?

Here is a rough example of my code in my main function:

```
r := gin.Default()
//ReqHandler is an HtttpHandler func
r.GET("/redirect", ReqHandler)

r.Run(":5001")
ContinueAuth()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a listener in the main goroutine. Start the HTTP server in a goroutine. Continue with auth flow in the main goroutine.

```
r := gin.Default()
r.GET("/redirect", ReqHandler)

l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":5001")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

go func() {
   log.Fatal(r.RunListener(l))
}()

ContinueAuth()

select {} // wait forever
```

Creating the listener in the main goroutine ensures that the listener is ready for callbacks from the authentication flow.

Comment: Quick question. That select { } wait forever? Or spin forever using CPU?

Answer (score 0):

> Note: this method will block the calling goroutine indefinitely unless an error happens.

The `r.Run()` will block the execution unless an error happens.

It is possible by running the `Run()` as go-routine and `ContinueAuth()` after it by.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/redirect", ReqHandler)

    go func() {
        // serve and listen
        if err := r.Run(":8080"); err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to start the server:", err)
            return
        }
    }()

    ContinueAuth()

    select {}
}
```

But `ContinueAuth` will run even when the `Run` raises an error too.

**So we have to handle it differently, as the ContinueAuth() should only run after the server has successfully started.**

- We will create a signal only channel, and start a go routine to listen the channel.
- When the signal received on the channel, we'll call `ContinueAuth()`
- We'll start another go-routine to send the signal into channel after 1 second. This is to wait for the server to run or fail.
- Start the server

Here is the implementation

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/redirect", ReqHandler)

    done := make(chan struct{}, 1)

    // this go routine wait for getting a signal in done channel.
    // On channel close, then we know the server is running successfully
    // If it is not running successfully, then it means something went wrong with the listening
    {
        go func(done chan struct{}) {
            // Check the channel is closed
            if _, ok := <-done; !ok {
                fmt.Println("Channel is closed.. The server is running successfully")
                ContinueAuth()
            }
        }(done)
    }

    // send the channel close signal after 1 second....
    // as this will only run if the server started sucessfully,
    // else this code will not execute, the execution will fail at immediately
    //
    // We are assuming the server will fail within 1 second when something went wrong
    go func(done chan struct{}) {
        time.Sleep(time.Second) // updated
        close(done)
    }(done)

    // serve and listen
    if err := r.Run(":8080"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to start the server:", err)
        return
    }

}

func ReqHandler(c *gin.Context) {
}

func ContinueAuth() {
    fmt.Println(".............. [ContinueAuth] ............... ")
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In this answer, there's a race between successful server start and the execution of `ContinueAuth`.  Server start will typically win the race because server start has a one second head start, but that's not guaranteed.  Also `time.Sleep(time.Second)` is a simpler way to wait one second than what's shown here.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted the answer from @thwd but I figured I would add the workaround that I am currently using in case anyone is interested (or in case it's bad and someone would like to correct me!).

I used a wait group and started the gin server in a GoRoutine:

```
func main(){
 var wg sync.WaitGroup

 wg.Add(1)

 go ConfigureGin(&wg)
 
 ContinueAuth()
 wg.Wait()
}

func ConfigureGin(wg *sync.WaitGroup){
 r := gin.Default()
 r.Get("/redirect",ReqHandler)
 r.Run(":5001")
 wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: Does the endpoint established in `ConfigureGin` need to be available for `ContinueAuth` to run?

Comment: @thwd Yes it would, I suppose that my method would create a race condition?